# String not containing whitespace followed by digit

Tags: regex, string, bash

I am trying to come up with a regex that returns a certain jpeg filename in a folder not containing a whitespace followed by digit at the end of the filename, e.g., `002504_GDG_EN_160902.jpeg` would be fine, `002504_GDG_EN_160902 5.jpeg` not.

My best guess so far is, with `$file` being the filename without the suffix and any number (e.g., `002504_GDG_EN_160902`):

```
test=$(ls *.jpeg | sort | grep $file | grep -v '.*\s\d\.jpeg')
```

This works fine for the the above mentioned example, but somehow not for cases where `$file` is `2016_MUC-Werk_[B_DGF_LA_LZ_R]_FG-8_all_160926`. Probably because of the brackets and/or minuses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use `ls` and `grep`.

Using `extglob`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob

printf "%s\n" +([^[:blank:]]).jpeg
002504_GDG_EN_160902.jpeg
```

Or to store matching filenames in an array:

```
files=(+([^[:blank:]]).jpeg)
```

`+([^[:blank:]]).jpeg` will match filenames with 1 or more non-space characters followed by `.jpeg`

Comment: Thanks! Worked very vell! I finally also solved it by simply using the `-F` option of `grep`. Thus, `test=$(ls *.jpeg | sort | grep $file | grep -v '.*\s\d\.jpeg')` worked in my case well, but your answer is way more versatile!

Comment: Sorry forgot the -F above, I meant `test=$(ls *.jpeg | sort | grep -F $file | grep -v '.*\s\d\.jpeg')`

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```
ls -1
002504_GDG_EN_16090 2.jpeg
002504_GDG_EN_160901 32.jpeg
002504_GDG_EN_1609012.jpeg
002504_GDG_EN_1609013.jpeg
2016_MUC-Werk_[B_DGF_LA_LZ_R]_FG-8_all_160926
```

solution using array:

```
array=(*)
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" |grep -Pv  '\d\s\d.*(.jpeg|$)'
002504_GDG_EN_1609012.jpeg
002504_GDG_EN_1609013.jpeg
2016_MUC-Werk_[B_DGF_LA_LZ_R]_FG-8_all_160926
```

to store it in any variable:

```
var=$(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" |grep -Pv  '\d\s\d.*(.jpeg|$)')

echo "$var"
002504_GDG_EN_1609012.jpeg
002504_GDG_EN_1609013.jpeg
2016_MUC-Werk_[B_DGF_LA_LZ_R]_FG-8_all_160926
```

Comment: ture, anubhav's answer is complete . this is alternate way of doing. can't find any harm is knowing it :)